# Sorting 2 Dimensional arrays Using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

No matter how I try I really cant get pass in this problem. As you can see I'm using pointers in the 2 dimensional arrays for sorting.

```
    int i,temp;
int *ptr;
int arry[1][8]={12,13,9,1,8,9,4,3};
int col,row; 
cout<<"First: ";
for(i = 0; i< 8;i++){
cout<<" "<<arry[0][i];  
}

cout<<endl;

for(col=0;col < 8;col++){
    for(row=col+1;row <= 8;row++){
        if(*(*(arry + 0) + col) > *(*(arry + 0) + row)){
            temp= *(*(arry + 0) + col);
            *(*(arry + 0) + col) = *(*(arry + 0) + row);
            *(*(arry + 0) + row) = temp;
        }
    }
}

cout<<"Output:";
for(i=0;i<8;i++) 
  cout<<" "<<arry[0][i];
```

Comment: isn't that not the same as *(*(sample + i) + j) ?

Comment: You are correct, I had a little typo and didn't notice it when I still could edit the post. So: I think what you need to really do is this: `*(*(arry + 0) + col)` instead of `*(*arry + 0) + col`. (Also you have some other problems with indexing, but that should cover the important part. The problem is, that prefix operator (such as dereference `*`) have higher priority than infix operators (such as `+`).)

Comment: I'm new programming but what I see is that temp is not an array, then I'm assigning a 2 dimensional array in the temp. So I think that's the problem maybe. Just my idea. I'm really stuck in this part.

Comment: Ok heres my new Code. 
for(col=0;col < 10;col++){
  for(row=col+1;row <= 10;row++){
   if((*(*arry + 0) + col) > *(*(arry + 0) + row)){
    temp=*(*arry + 0) + col;
    *(*arry + 0) + col = *(*arry + 0) + row;
    *(*arry + 0) + row = temp;
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Show the definition of the array (or the pointer) and it is strange that at first you output a row that has 8 columns but inside the loops there is used 10 columns.

Comment: Ill update my question sorry for my disturbance :)

Comment: does the updated version work, or what is now the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are just storing values in the array, not pointers.

Changing the notation so that your existing loop to more conventional array addressing we would have something like this which may be more readable.

```
if(arry[0][col]) > arry[0][row]){
    temp=arry[0][col];
    arry[0][col] = arry[0][row];
    arry[0][row] = temp;
}
```

If you want to use pointer notation, you can substitute arry[i][j] with *(*(arry+i)+j) but this is the same thing.  Are you wishing to achieve something extra via the pointer notation?

Comment: Well I know Im using a 2 dimensional array but I just put 0 on the row. But i wanted to swap the values using a pointer